# Indents in lxml.etree.tostring() vary among Mac and Linux

Tags: python, linux, macos, lxml

Python's lxml.etree.tostring() indents differently on the Mac and Linux -- indents seem to be twice as long as those on Linux. It's blowing up my unit tests.

Apparently lxml.etree doesn't expose any path for setting default indent values.

Anyone have any idea what could be going on here?

EDITED TO ADD CODE:

I'm sure the code is the same, the computers share it via github.

Here is the test code:

```
    chk = """\
<field>
      <id>7135260</id>
      <name>lastname</name>
      <label>Last Name</label>
      <type/>
    </field>"""

        res = etree.tostring((xml_obj.xpath(xp_str))[0], pretty_print=True)

        self.assertMultiLineEqual(
            chk,
            res.rstrip()
        )
```

This passes on Linux, but fails on the Mac, with this error report:

```
-       <id>7135260</id>
+             <id>7135260</id>
? ++++++
-       <name>lastname</name>
+             <name>lastname</name>
? ++++++
-       <label>Last Name</label>
+             <label>Last Name</label>
? ++++++
-       <type/>
+             <type/>
? ++++++
-     </field>
+         </field>
? ++++
```

BUT when I isolate the offending code, it outputs the same on both:

```
data_str    =   """\
<response>
  <fields>
    <field>
      <id>7135259</id>
      <name>firstname</name>
      <label>First Name</label>
      <type/>
    </field>
    <field>
      <id>7135260</id>
      <name>lastname</name>
      <label>Last Name</label>
      <type/>
    </field>
  </fields>
  <status>success</status>
</response>
"""

data_xml    =   etree.fromstring(data_str)

res = etree.tostring(
        (data_xml.xpath('//*[name="lastname"]/name/..'))[0], 
        pretty_print=True)

print res
```

That gives the same indentation on both platforms.

So whatever the weirdness may be, it is some located in / induced by unittest2.  This probably isn't a very good question at this point.

FURTHER EDIT:

When I wrap the comparison items in repr(), I get this:

```
- '<field>\n      <id>7135260</id>\n      <name>lastname</name>\n      <label>Last Name</label>\n      <type/>\n    </field>'
+ '<field>\n            <id>7135260</id>\n            <name>lastname</name>\n            <label>Last Name</label>\n            <type/>\n        </field>\n        \n'
?           ++++++                        ++++++                                   ++++++                                ++++++             ++++        ++++++++++++
```

That output actually comes in a single line.  I've inserted the line breaks first + sign and the ? character.

I've searched the test output for tabs ('\t').  I'm sure I'm not inserting tab characters, I'm using vi w/ 'set expandtab'.

Comment: I'd use a different library---I've found `etree` to be quite poor in regards to printing/formatting XML.

Answer (score 2):

Are you using *exactly* the same args to `tostring()` in each case? Have you tried turning off indentation to check if that is truly the problem?

Show us your code that calls tostring(). Create a small example tree and show us the result of print len(result_of_tostring), repr(result_of_tostring) on each OS. Also tell us about how you transport a result to the other system for comparison, and show us the code for that comparison.

**Update**: The indentation of your "chk" string looks suspicious. I suggest that there is nothing wrong with lxml, and you have an experimental error that has whitespace differences. Have you eliminated all TABs from your code? Are you sure that you didn't open/save your code with an editor that replaces tabs with spaces or vice versa? *Why don't you use repr() as suggested to show exactly/unambiguously what the unequal strings are?*

**Update 2**: Search your **source code** for tabs. Your displayed source for "chk" has an indentation of 6 for most lines.

Comment: No tabs in source -- as noted, source edited in vi, set to use spaces rather than tabs.

Answer (score 1):

You could write an assertXMLEqual method that just strips the indentation before comparing. Your tests should be checking that the xml dom from the function you test is correct, the way it is serialised and indented is irrelevant to that.